# How to calculate percentage & identify the row containing identify the row & State containing the maximum value from unstacked dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a unstacked dataframe like this

[image]

How can I calculate the percentage and identify which state has the highest percentage of open cases

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
statewise_group['perc'] = statewise_group['Open'].div(statewise_group['Open'].sum())

state = statewise_group['perc'].idxmax()
```